# Extended Ternary expression

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I know you can do ternary expressions in Javascript for an if - else statement, but how about an else- else if- else statement? I thought that surely this would be supported but I haven't been able to find any info about it and wasn't able to get it to work just hacking around.

Comment: You will have to explain to us what you mean by "else- else if- else" statement. Do you mean "if ... else if ... else"?

Comment: Check this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393520/convert-nested-if-statements-to-more-elegant-switch/6393547#6393547

Comment: +1 for the thought. Though like we've all said readability gets tough with the more conditions you add. Sometimes though regular ifs are the choice of kings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrast to Robby Cornelissen's answer - there is no problems with readability if you format it properly (and not writing PHP, since it messed up the operator by making it left-associative in contrast to all other languages that have that construct):

```
var y =
  x == 0 ? "zero" :
  x == 1 ? "one" :
  "other";
```

**EDIT**

> What I was looking for is a shorter version of "if expression 1 is true, return expression 1. Else if expression 2 is true, return expression 2. Else return expression 3". Is there no clean way to do this?

There is: `expression1 || expression2 || expression3`. (It would have been nice if you had put this into your question in the first place.) This is commonly used for default values:

```
var defaults = null;
function hello(name) {
  var displayName = name || (defaults && defaults.name) || "Anonymous";
  console.log("Hello, " + displayName + ".");
}

hello("George");
// => Hello, George.
hello();
// => Hello, Anonymous.
defaults = {};
hello();
// => Hello, Anonymous.
defaults.name = "You"
hello();
// => Hello, You.
```

However, it is important to be aware of the conditions for truthiness. For example, if you expect `""` or `0` to be a valid value that does not need to be replaced by a default, the code will fail; this trick only works when the set of possible non-default values is exactly the set of truthy values, no more and no less. E.g.

```
function increment(val, by) {
    return val + (by || 1);      // BUG
}

increment(10, 4);
// => 14
increment(10, 1);
// => 11
increment(10);
// => 11
increment(10, 0);
// => 11                         <-- should be 10
```

In this case you need to be explicit:

```
function increment(val, by) {
    return val + (typeof(by) === "undefined" ? 1 : by);
}
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for thanks. Nice and clean =). Upvote + 1 and I will accept the answer when I can

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it because of readability, but you could just nest ternary operators:

```
var y = (x == 0 ? "zero" : (x == 1 ? "one" : "other"));
```

This would be the equivalent of:

```
var y;

if (x == 0) {
    y = "zero";
} else if (x == 1) {
    y = "one";
} else {
    y = "other";
}
```

Comment: Let me explain a little more
Your normal ternary operator is :
    return express1 ? express1 : express2

In that case, we can compare 2 expressions and decide which one is going to be returned based on the value of the first expression. What I was looking for is a shorter version of "if expression 1 is true, return expression 1. Else if expression 2 is true, return expression 2. Else return expression 3". Is there no clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend a ternary condition if you're good. It gets to be messy though.

```
var number = 5;
var power = 2;
var ans = Math.pow(number,power);
var suggest = (  ans == 5 ? 5 : ans == 10 ? 10 : ans == 15 ? 15 : ans == 25 ? "works" : null);
console.log(suggest);
```

I may have added to many because I'm on my phone haha but try it in your developer panel.